# bit fields in c programming

Tags: c, structure, bit-fields

Here in this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    struct bits{
        unsigned a:5;
        unsigned b:5;
        char c;
        int d;
    } bit1;

    printf("%d",sizeof(bit1));
}
```

the output is `5`
please explain how did 5 come

Comment: search hundred of duplicate about this on SO.

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: I want to know how 5 comes that i expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using `Turbo C(windows)`. In `TurboC` compiler by default `integer` is `short` integer which is of `2 bytes(16 bits)`.

Next come to `sizeof`, you are trying to print sizeof structure, which is nothing `sum of sizeof all data member`.

The first member of `struct bits` is `unsigned a : 5`, when compiler will see first see `unsigned` it allocates `2 bytes or 16 bits` for this, `out of 16 bits` you are using only `5 bits` i.e still you can store `11 bits`.

The next member is `unsigned b:5` this will be served in `same previous memory`, so still size is `2 bytes`. till now memory allocation will be looks like

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   p |   p |   p | p | p | p | b | b | b | b | b | a | a | a | a | a |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0x115 0x114 0x113..         ........                               0x100
MSB                                                                LSB 
a means for a 5 bits
b means for b 5 bits
p means padding or wastage.
```

if you analyse above figure, **first 5 bits for a**, **next 5 bits for b**, now how many pending out of `16 bits` ? `6 bits` right ? can you store a `char(8 bit)` in remaining `6 bits`, answer is `No`. So remaining `6 bits will be holes in structure`(I shown is `p` which is `padding`)

So next for `char c` it will again allocate separate `1 bytes`, so till now `2+1 = 3 bytes`.

Next member of structure is `d` which is again integer, so for this `2 byte`s will be allocated. So total `2+1+ 2 = 5 bytes` will be allocated for whole structure.

I hope you got it.

Comment: `c` is stored in a separate object not because the eight bits it needs do not fit in the bits remaining in the bytes allocated for `a` and `b` but because it is a regular object, not a bit-field, so it is stored separately regardless. This is per 6.2.6.1 of C 2011, but note 2 (paragraph 3) of clause 3.14 tell us explicitly: “A bit-field and an adjacent non-bit-field member are in separate memory locations.”